# Interop Assembly Embedd

Tags: visual-studio, com, nuget-package, com-interop, csproj

I have a Library created as NuGet which in turn depends a COM component  thru Interop, I am adding the Interop Assembly as part of my NuGet. When I use the NuGet in Client App. the tag `<EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>` get automatically added to the client **csproj** file for the Interop assembly , But When I run the app,  it complains the interop assembly could not  found. Hence I converted to `<EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>` so that the interop `dll` is available and it works fine . But whenever the new version of the NuGet is updated, it Visual studio update it back to `<EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>`. Is there a settings where I can make it default `false` whenever the NuGet is added. Like as part of the NuGet or as part of the Client Project